# Any counter example for $P(A|C)=P(A),P(B|C)=P(B)$ but $P(A\cap B|C)\neq P(A\cap B)$?

Tags: probability, examples-counterexamples

Let $A,B,C$ be three events, what would be an example that $P(A|C)=P(A)$ and $P(B|C)=P(B)$ **do not** imply $P(A\cap B|C)= P(A\cap B)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a dice with 8 faces with numbers from $1$ to $8$ on them respectively. We roll that dice. Denote $X$ as the resulting face.

Let $A=[X=1,X=2]$, $B = [X=2,X = 3]$, $C=[X~\text{is even}]$.  Then we definitely have $$P(A|C)=P(X=2\vert C)=\frac14=P(A)$$ and $$P(B|C)=P(X=2\vert C)=\frac14=P(B).$$

But $$P(A\cap B|C) = P(X = 2\vert C) = \frac14\ne \frac18 = P(X = 2) = P(A\cap B) $$

Answer (score 3):

Let $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4\}$ be the sample space, events $A = \{1,2\}$, $B = \{1,3\}$, $C = \{1,4\}$.

\begin{align}
P(A|C) &= P(\text{choose 1 or 2 | 1 or 4 chosen}) = \frac12 \\
P(A) &= P(\text{choose 1 or 2}) = \frac12 = P(A|C) \\
P(B|C) &= P(B) = \frac12 \quad \text{similarly} \\
P(A\cap B | C) &= P(\text{choose 1 | 1 or 4 chosen}) = \frac12, \text{ but} \\
P(A\cap B) &= P(\text{choose 1}) = \frac14 \ne P(A\cap B | C).
\end{align}